# Modified branching process problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm having trouble with the following problem:

> Let $\xi_i$ be i.i.d random variables with distribution,
>
> $$P(\xi_i = k) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2} & k = 0 \\ \frac{1}{4} & k = 1 \\ \frac{1}{4} & k = 2\end{cases}$$
>
> Let $X_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{X_{n-1}}\xi_k$ and assume $X_0 = 0$. In a typical branching process, the state $0$ is absorbing, i.e $P(X_{n+1} = 0 | X_n = 0) = 1$. However, suppose we modify this so that there is a positive probability of "regenerating" after extinction. Specifically, suppose that,$$P(X_{n+1} = 1 | X_n = 0) = \frac{1}{3} = 1 - P(X_{n+1} = 0 | X_n = 0)$$
>
> Let $T = \inf\{n \geq 1: X_n = 0\}$ be the first hitting time of state $0$. **Find the expectation, $E[T]$**.

Finding this expectation is tricky because there doesn't seem to be a nice way of computing $P(T = n)$ for any $n$. The $n = 1$ case is nice because,

$$ P(T = 1) = P(X_1 = 0 | X_0 = 0) = \dfrac{1}{3} $$

Similarly, the $n = 2$ case isn't too bad,

$$ P(T = 2) = P(X_2 = 0 | X_1 = 1)P(X_1 = 1 | X_0 = 0) = \dfrac{1}{5}\dfrac{1}{3} = \dfrac{1}{15} $$

However, things start to become quite tedious even for $n = 3$. Is there a more efficient way of computing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X_1=0$ then $T=1$. Else the typical branching process starts with initial unit number of particles, and for the time $T'$ of its extinction, 
$$\mathbb E[T]=1+\frac13\mathbb E[T'|X_1=1]$$
But the extinction probability is $1/2$, so $\mathbb E[T'|X_1=1]=\infty$ since $T'=\infty$ w.p. $1/2$.

Comment: My apologies, I wrote the incorrect offspring probabilities. The goal of the question is in fact to show that E[T] is finite. Hopefully the edited problem makes things more clear.

Comment: In this cases the problem is reduced to finding the expectation of $T'$ - extinction time of branching process started at $1$. If only existence is interesting, then $$\mathbb P(T'\geq n)=\mathbb P(X_n\geq 1\mid X_0=1)\leq \mathbb E[X_n\mid X_0=1]=(3/4)^n,$$ and $\mathbb E[T']<\infty.$ To find it one need to find $\mathbb P(T'=n)=f_{n+1}(0)-f_{n}(0)$, where $f_k(z)=f(f(\ldots f(z)))$ ($k$ times) and $f(z)=\mathbb E[z^{\xi_1}]$ is a probability generating function of a typical number of offsprings of a single particle. Doubt that it is simple task.